# No default constructor for entity

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I'm trying to create an API and i've made this code so far:

```
@Builder
@Data
@Entity
public class IcesiUser {
    @Id
    private UUID userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<IcesiAccount> accounts;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "icesi_role_role_id")
    private IcesiRole role;}
```

This is the repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<IcesiUser, UUID> {@Query("select u from IcesiUser u where u.email = ?1")Optional<IcesiUser> findByEmail(String email);

@Query("select u from IcesiUser u where u.phoneNumber = ?1")
Optional<IcesiUser> findByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);

}
```

And this is the service that saves the user

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;
    public IcesiUser save(UserCreateDTO user) {
        Optional<IcesiUser> userFoundByEmail = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        Optional<IcesiUser> userFoundByPhoneNumber = userRepository.findByPhoneNumber(user.getPhoneNumber());
        if(userFoundByEmail.isPresent() || userFoundByPhoneNumber.isPresent()){
            throw new RuntimeException("User already exists");
        }else{
            IcesiUser icesiUser = userMapper.fromIcesiUserDTO(user);
            icesiUser.setUserId(UUID.randomUUID());
            return userRepository.save(icesiUser);
        }

    }
    public Optional<IcesiUser> findUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public Optional<IcesiUser> findUserByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        return userRepository.findByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

It runs but when I send a POST request via the controller it appears the exception of
`org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.TallerJPA.model.IcesiUser`

I have another project as an example and it doesnt have much difference, does anyone know why is this happening?

I've tried making a normal builder in the IcesiUser class but when I try to run the application an error shows up.

Also I tried adding @Getter and @Setter as I saw in another post but it does nothing.

Comment: I don't think that using data annotation is good.  you had better to add the functions you used only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using JPA, entities must have a default (no-argument) constructor.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class IcesiUser {
    // ... (your fields)

    public IcesiUser() {
    }

    // to keep the builder pattern, you can create an all-argument constructor:
    @Builder
    public IcesiUser(UUID userId, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phoneNumber, String password, List<IcesiAccount> accounts, IcesiRole role) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.password = password;
        this.accounts = accounts;
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```